# In what Units does QSvgGenerator operate in?

Tags: c++, svg, qt5, resolution, dpi

In the official documentation for [QSvgGenerator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvggenerator.html#details) there are two properties that relate to the size of the output. One is `size` and the other is `resolution`.

Resolution is set in DPI (Dots Per Inch), but which unit is size in?

I have tested multiple values now and none make sense to me when inspecting the output file.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the generated SVG file? Maybe it's something SVG specific...

Comment: I did not, I will do that. Good idea! The reason I ask this question is that I am "printing" to svg as a form of preview but if they don't use comparable units it all sort of voides the purpose. Also in inkscape I am able to set mm as unit and I was hoping that mm in inkscae would correspond to mm in my print using QPrinter

Comment: Found this to be very useful: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html. Apparently in svg the lack of spesific units defaults to pixels. The viewbox and viewbox defined which part of the document is shown. In the output from QSvgGenerator viewport was specified in mm while viewbox  and all the rest of elements/shapes in file was specified without units.

Answer (score 1):

size is in pixels.  If you treat size as pixels then the output SVG width and height attributes will be approximately the correct number of mm.